# Gram Schmidt Orthonormalisation

Tags: matlab

I am writing the following code for Gram Schmidt Orthogonalization. It says that there's an error in calling the function. What's the error and how to rectify it?

```
A =[1,1,1,1;-1,4,4,-1;4,-2,2,0];
A =A';
B=myGramschmidt(A);

function [B] = myGramschmidt(A)
x1=A(:,1);
x2=A(:,2);

x3=A(:,3);
v1=x1;
c = dot(v1);
v2 = x2-((dot(x2,v1)/c)* v1);
d = dot(v2);
v3 = x3-((dot(x3,v1)/c)* v1)-((dot(x3,v2)/d)* v2);
C=[v1,v2,v3];
V1=normc(v1);
V2=normc(v2);
V3=normc(v3);
B=[V1,V2,V3];
end
```

Comment: The [`dot`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) function requires two (ort three) inputs

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Wikipedia Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#The_Gram.E2.80.93Schmidt_process) page, but Luis Mendo is correct as to why you got the error.

```
function [B] = myGramschmidt(A)
    B = A;

    for k = 1:size(A, 1)
        for j = 1:k-1
            B(k, :) = B(k, :) - proj(B(j, :), A(k, :));
        end
    end
end

function p = proj(u, v)
% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#The_Gram.E2.80.93Schmidt_process
    p = dot(v, u) / dot(u, u) * u;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this vectorized implementation in python.

Also I would suggest to go through David C lay book for theory.

```
def replace_zero(array): 
    
    for i in range(len(array)) :
        if array[i] == 0 : 
            array[i] = 1
    return array
```

```
def gram_schmidt(self,A, norm=True, row_vect=False):
        """Orthonormalizes vectors by gram-schmidt process

        Parameters
        -----------
        A : ndarray,
        Matrix having vectors in its columns

        norm : bool,
        Do you need Normalized vectors?

        row_vect: bool,
        Does Matrix A has vectors in its rows?

        Returns
        -------
        G : ndarray,
        Matrix of orthogonal vectors
        
        Gram-Schmidt Process
        --------------------
        The Gram–Schmidt process is a simple algorithm for 
        producing an orthogonal or orthonormal basis for any 
        nonzero subspace of Rn.

        Given a basis {x1,....,xp} for a nonzero subspace W of Rn,
        define

        v1 = x1
        v2 = x2 - (x2.v1/v1.v1) * v1
        v3 = x3 - (x3.v1/v1.v1) * v1  - (x3.v2/v2.v2) * v2
         .
         .
         .
        vp = xp - (xp.v1/v1.v1) * v1  - (xp.v2/v2.v2) * v2 - ....... 
             .... - (xp.v(p-1) / v(p-1).v(p-1) ) * v(p-1)


        Then {v1,.....,vp} is an orthogonal basis for W .
        In addition,
        Span {v1,.....,vp} = Span {x1,.....,xp}    for 1 <= k <= p

        References
        ----------
        Linear Algebra and Its Applications - By David.C.Lay

        """
        if row_vect :
            # if true, transpose it to make column vector matrix
            A = A.T

        no_of_vectors = A.shape[1]
        G = A[:,0:1].copy() # copy the first vector in matrix
        # 0:1 is done to to be consistent with dimensions - [[1,2,3]]

        # iterate from 2nd vector to number of vectors
        for i in range(1,no_of_vectors):

            # calculates weights(coefficents) for every vector in G
            numerator = A[:,i].dot(G)
            denominator = np.diag(np.dot(G.T,G)) #to get elements in diagonal
            weights = np.squeeze(numerator/denominator)

            # projected vector onto subspace G
            projected_vector = np.sum(weights * G,
                                      axis=1,
                                      keepdims=True)

            # orthogonal vector to subspace G
            orthogonalized_vector = A[:,i:i+1] - projected_vector

            # now add the orthogonal vector to our set
            G = np.hstack((G,orthogonalized_vector))

        if norm :
            # to get orthoNormal vectors (unit orthogonal vectors)
            # replace zero to 1 to deal with division by 0 if matrix has 0 vector
            # or normazalization value comes out to be zero
            G = G/self.replace_zero(np.linalg.norm(G,axis=0))

        if row_vect:
            return G.T

        return G
```

```
G = np.array([[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
gram_schmidt(G)
>
array([[ 0.5       , -0.8660254 ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.28867513, -0.81649658],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.28867513,  0.40824829],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.28867513,  0.40824829]])
```